# what is the general method to add opencv in visual studio for all programs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to  setting up opencv for my project in visual studio and for this I have seen so many blogs and forums but still I didn't find any way to add openCv in generalized way so every time I make new project, it should be added automatically. Is there any way to add openCv in visual studio so every time when I will make new project it should be added automatically, please share your answers. I want to save my time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vcpkg is a package manager which helps you to manage C and C++ libraries on Windows, Linux and MacOS, available on [GitHub.](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)

Use vcpkg in the PowerShell command prompt `.\vcpkg install opencv` to install opencv and issue command `.\vcpkg integrate install` to integrate installed packages into your Visual Studio projects.

Comment: if you have some link, please tell in detail. I am new in this field

Comment: Updated with link to GitHub. You can directly compile the vcpkg code in your VS C++ to generate the vcpkg executable.